# Vantagens da Inner Class

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Desde que comecei a programar para Android (acredito que devido ao exemplos do Google), tenho o hábito de criar classes internas para funcionalidades relacionadas a `Activity`.

*Exemplo*: Se a `Activity` realiza conexão com o banco (e se a requisição é específica desta tela), crio uma classe interna que extende de `AsyncTask`.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma vantagem em usar esta esta abordagem?

Existe algum ganho na performance?

Ou apenas é apenas uma questão estrutural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No que diz respeito ao *Android* e especificamente ao uso de *Inner Class* em uma *Activity* a sua preocupação deve-se focar nos problemas que ele(uso) pode trazer no que diz respeito a [Memory Leaks](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vazamento_de_mem%C3%B3ria).

O ciclo de vida de uma *Activity* não é totalmente controlado por nós, podendo ser destruída a qualquer momento pelo SO.

Uma *Inner Class*, que não seja declarada *static*, ou uma *anonymous inner class* mantêm uma referência implícita à Activity o que poderá evitar que a memória alocada por ela seja reclamada, quando for destruída e recriada, durante uma alteração de configuração(rotação do dispositivo por exemplo).

Por isso qualquer vantagem(é discutível se há algum) que o uso de *Inner Class* possa trazer está condicionado à existência ou não do perigo de [Memory Leaks](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vazamento_de_mem%C3%B3ria).

Para leitura:
[How to Leak a Context: Handlers & Inner Classes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)
[Activitys, Threads, & Memory Leaks](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html)
[When exactly is it leak safe to use (anonymous) inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10864853/2556111)

Answer (score 4):

O uso de `Inner Class` faz o total sentido em vários casos. Se nenhuma outra classe precisa/utiliza ela, torne-a privada. Se ela não necessita de um acesso exclusivo de outros membros de outras classes, torne-a estática por que isso irá faze-la alocar menos memória. Na [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html):

> Use a non-static nested class (or inner class) if you require access
>   to an enclosing instance's non-public fields and methods. Use a static
>   nested class if you don't require this access.

Porém, um outro ponto de vista, é se sua classe já estiver gigantesca. Quer dizer, com um número excessivo de linhas. Vários desenvolvedores não gostam de utilizar `Inner Class` para não aumentar a quantidade de linhas de sua classe.

Como tudo, utilize com sabedoria e bom senso para usufruir de uma arquitetura saudável.

Answer (score 3):

É apenas estrutural! No processo de compilação, cada Inner Class é feita separadamente e tem até um pouco mais de atenção do *GarbageCollector*(Não posso garantir que tenha maior performance). Na prática, elas são muito mais rápidas de serem desenvolvidas e deixa tudo mais organizado.

Se você olhar qualquer código fonte oficial da **Oracle** , vai notar muito o uso de Inner Class.

Answer (score 3):

Nota: esta é uma resposta complementar à do @ramaral.

A noção de ter cuidado com vazamento de memória é real e muito importante. Contudo, após ler os dois artigos citados eu diria que, no mínimo, eles possuem o fico errado.

Que dizer com isso que o problema não está nas classes internas e sim em você *referenciar activities ou outros objetos descartáveis em objetos que persistem*.

Faz tanto sentido colocar a culpa nas classes internas quanto no uso de threads.

Ora, não importa se é uma classe interna ou não, estática ou não, a tentação de referenciar a activity é grande e as chances são de que o desenvolvedor eventualmente vai passar a referência para a outra classe de alguma forma. Em outras palavras: qualquer objeto com uma referência à Activity pode causar o memory leak. Pode, inclusive, ser uma inner class dentro de um método em outra classe que acessa a Activity recebida no parâmetro daquele método.

Em alguns exemplos nos artigos citados, é dito que a máquina virtual não limpa as threads. Correto, mas isso é verdade em qualquer caso. Então, mesmo o "bom" exemplo do artigo ainda apresenta um memory leak. Ele pode não vazar a Activity, mas com certeza vaza threads, pois elas não são destruídas nunca. Isso pode ser tão ruim quanto o consumo a mais de memória, já que o aplicativo terá um número crescente de threads fazendo a mesma coisa ao mesmo tempo.

Portanto, mais do que se preocupar com as sutilezas das classes internas, o desenvolvedor deve atentar para limpar os recursos alocados ou pelo menos verificar se eles já não estão alocados.

Quanto ao uso de classes internas, como os demais já disseram, a maior questão é estrutural, já que elas são compiladas separadamente das classes principais em arquivos `.class` individuais.

Porém, é interessante que classes internas podem acessar métodos privados da classe principal é vice-versa. Está é uma vantagem se você quer manter o encapsulamento de alguns elementos.

Enfim, se você estiver dando visibilidade para algum método ou atributo somente para que uma determinada classe possa acessá-los, talvez deva considerar o uso de uma classe interna ou outra opção de design.

No Java em geral, o uso de classes internas é extenso, desde o código do próprio Java até o incentivo ao uso de lambdas na versão 8. Quem adere a técnicas de programação funcional não pode ter medo e tenho visto muitos softwares renomados fazendo uso extensivo de classes internas.

Resumo: não tenha medo de classes internas. Mesmo os melhores desenvolvedores não conseguem entender ou prever todas as sutilezas que podem causar problemas numa aplicação ou aplicativo. Mas é imprescindível, como fez o autor do artigo, que você aprenda técnicas para monitorar e diagnosticar os problemas e não apenas confie que tudo vai.dar certo porque você seguiu as regras X ou Y.

Comment: Se a *inner class* não for declarada *static* ela sempre terá uma referência à *outer class*. Caso ela seja uma Activity ou outra que possa ser destruída pelo Android, poderá provocar *memory leaks*. Ou seja *"... se é uma classe interna ou não, estática ou não"* importa caso a *outer class* seja um Activity.